# magento add product in multishipping quote

Tags: magento, quote

In multishipping, I have to allow giftwrapping, when user selects any wrap for any quote of multishipping, I have to add a wrapper product for that particular quote. I have used `checkout_controller_multishipping_shipping_post` event and got the quote.

Now when I use `$quote->addproduct($wrapperProductObject)` it does add this product in db table but doesn't show on order(s) review page until I go to cart page and come again.

Is there is way to add a product in quote after mentioned event and it shows on order review page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why magento has another table for address items instead of having a field in quote_items table. Anyway the answer of my question is we need to update quote_address_item table as well.

Below code works fine for my problem.

`$item = $quote->addProduct($wrapperProductObj, $qty);
 $quote->save();
//need to add item in quote_address_items table. 
 $address->addItem($item);`